# Python 2.7t: Is it possible to set the sensitivity of a 'motion_notify_event' (mouse hover)

Tags: python, canvas

I am making a plot with datapoints that display a value when the mouse hovers over the datapoint but the value will only display if you hover very precisely. Is there a way to decrease the sensitivity of this action. 
I am using QtCore and QtGui to create a canvas to which I add the motion_notify_event.

```
def make_UI_elements(self):
self.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.on_hover)

def on_hover(self, event):
        self.fig_text.set_text('')

        contains, attrd = self.points.contains(event)
        if contains == True:
            ind = attrd['ind'][0]
            self.fig_text.set_text('bm {}'.format(self.model.benchmarks[ind]))
            # self.canvas.draw()
        self.canvas.draw()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use set_pickradius() for the item that should respond to hovering/clicking

```
 your_variable.set_pickradius()
```